# поведение margin в flexbox, а именно justify-content: space-around?

Tags: css3, flexbox

Хотелось бы узнать как ведут себя margin при justify-content: space-around , а именно как рассчитывает браузер сколько нужно оступть от правого края и левого , и как это можно высчитать в пикселях, ибо  в инспекторе глухо не показывает ни margin ни padding, буду благодарен за помощь.

Answer (score 0):

Там как такового margin и нет. Есть поведение браузера. Конкретно по **justify-content: space-around**

- Элементы равномерно распределены внутри контейнера выравнивания вдоль
  основной оси.
- Расстояние между каждой парой смежных элементов одинаково.
- Пустое пространство перед первым и после последнего элемента равно половине пространства между каждой парой смежных элементов.

Это из документации. То есть вначале опеделяется ширина «содержательных» элментов, после пустое место распределяется по описанному выше правилу.